# iOS: Webview not scaling when switching to landscape mode

Tags: ios, uiwebview, orientation, scaling

Since upgrading to Xcode 4.2, web views do not scale correctly when I change orientation

I use this code:

```
NSLog(@"Show link: %@",URL);

[showStory loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]];

showStory.scalesPageToFit = YES;

showStory.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But this happens when I switch to landscape mode.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this

 webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: webView.autoresizingMask fixed it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tick the scales page to fit option in the webView Attribute inspector.

Comment: Hi Clarence:  I forgot to add that I do have that already checked.  The odd thing is that if I pinch and zoom the page above, it does not scale into the white, right hand side of the screen. It seems as if it thinks the web page is constrained within a the partial view.

Comment: Did you put the following line in the code? return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

Comment: I actually use: return YES; so user can use any orietntation

Comment: Is your view mode of the web view set to "scale to fill"? Otherwise, I have also no idea about it.

Comment: Found the answer.  I deleted the entire class and NIB and started again.  This time everything worked fine.  Thanks for your help.